# How to delete objects in Sharepoint with C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a list generated by SSIS conditional split.
I tried to delete in sharepoint site from each item from the list using C#
However,  I execute the `deleteobject()` ; and the `context.ExecuteQuery()`; it catch the following error  :

> [Move SP SOQ [297]] Error: Error on ExecuteQuery SP Insert.Item does
> not exist.

The page you selected contains an item that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.

```
        //Authentification au site SP page prncipale
        string url = Variables.ListURLdelete;
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
        context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Variables.WebServiceServerUserName, Variables.WebServiceServerPassword);

        Web web = context.Web;
      
        List SOQList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SOQ");
        var item = SOQList.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
        if (Row.SOQENDDate >= 10)
        {

            if (!Row.Assignment_IsNull)
            {
                item["SOQAssignmentCode"] = Row.Assignment;
            }
            //if (!Row.AssignmentLabel_IsNull)
            //{
            //    item["SOQAssignmentStatus"] = Row.AssignmentLabel;
            //}
            //if (!Row.SOQTitle_IsNull)
            //{
            //    item["Title"] = Row.SOQTitle;
            //}
            //Insertion dans SP
            // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee539976(v=office.14)
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
                item.DeleteObject();
            }
            catch (Exception d)
            {
                ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "", "Error on Update Items SP Insert." + d.Message, "", 0, out vbool);
            }
            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception d)
            {
                ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "", "Error on ExecuteQuery SP Insert." + d.Message, "", 0, out vbool);
            }
        }

    }
```

Could it be that the error is on the **List SOQList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SOQ");** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Authentification au site SP page prncipale
        string url = Variables.Test;
        ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url);
        context.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
        context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Variables.WebServiceServerUserName, Variables.WebServiceServerPassword);

        Web web = context.Web;

        List SOQList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SOQ");

        if (Row.SOQStartDate >= 10 & !Row.SPID_IsNull)
        {
             This creates a CamlQuery that has a RowLimit of 100, and also specifies Scope="RecursiveAll"
             so that it grabs all list items, regardless of the folder they are in.
            CamlQuery query = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
            ListItemCollection items = SOQList.GetItems(query);


            context.Load(SOQList, list => list.ItemCount);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            int startcount = SOQList.ItemCount;
            // delete du status
            ListItem listItem = SOQList.GetItemById(Row.SPID); -->OK

            try
            {
                listItem.DeleteObject();
                // SOQList.Update();

            }
            catch (Exception d)
            {
                ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "", "Error on Update Items SP Insert." + d.Message, "", 0, out vbool);
            }
            try
            {
                context.ExecuteQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception d)
            {
                ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "", "Error on ExecuteQuery SP Update." + d.Message, "", 0, out vbool);
            }
            context.Load(SOQList, list => list.ItemCount);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            int endcount = SOQList.ItemCount;
            Console.WriteLine("Start: {0}  End: {1}", startcount, endcount);
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).